# Travis CI build running deploy stage on master even though tag condition is not met

Tags: java, maven, github, travis-ci, release

I have the following `.travis.yml` file in my project, configured to build always and to deploy only when the build is triggered by a GitHub tag matching a certain version string:

```
language: java
sudo: false
cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/.cache"
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      jdk: oraclejdk8
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      jdk: openjdk8
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      jdk: oraclejdk11
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      jdk: openjdk11
    - stage: deploy
      os: linux
      jdk: openjdk8
stages:
  - build
  - name: deploy
    if: tag =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
install:
  - gpg --version
  - mvn process-resources -B -V -e
script:
  - mvn test -B -V -e
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script:
      - openssl aes-256-cbc ... -in .travis.gpg.enc -out .travis.gpg -d
      - openssl aes-256-cbc ... -in .travis.settings.xml.enc -out .travis.settings.xml -d
      - gpg --import .travis.gpg
      - cp .travis.settings.xml $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
      - mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -P sign -B -V -e
    skip_cleanup: true
  - provider: releases
    api_key:
      secure: CKKEi9hoN...xbzZByUU80Q=
    file_glob: true
    file:
      - $HOME/.m2/repository/path/to/project-*.pom
      - $HOME/.m2/repository/path/to/porject-*.pom.asc
```

This worked fine when I pushed my branch: The Travis CI build ran and said it was skipping the deploy stage because the condition wasn't met. However, when I merged this branch into master, the Travis CI build ran against master (correct) and invoked the deploy stage (incorrect), attempting to deploy to Maven/GitHub (and failing due to what I believe is an unrelated error).

Oddly, it's not that it started the deploy `job` (it didn't; it only started the build `job`s). It added the deploy stage to the first four (build) `job`s (the ones that say `stage: build`). This is shown in the screenshot below, where you can see that it ran the four build jobs, and they all failed (specifically, they all failed on the deploy stage, but they shouldn't have tried to deploy; only the deploy job should deploy).

[image: Failed Travis CI build]

So, two questions:

1. What did I do wrong here that made it try to deploy from master even though it wasn't a tag?
2. Any idea what the following error is that (thankfully) made the deploy fail, and what I need to do to fix it?

Deploy error:

```
$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl
Successfully installed dpl-1.10.6
Parsing documentation for dpl-1.10.6
Installing ri documentation for dpl-1.10.6
Done installing documentation for dpl after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
Successfully installed dpl-script-1.10.6
Parsing documentation for dpl-script-1.10.6
Installing ri documentation for dpl-script-1.10.6
Done installing documentation for dpl-script after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/cli.rb:54:in `system': wrong first argument (ArgumentError)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/cli.rb:54:in `shell'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-script-1.10.6/lib/dpl/provider/script.rb:19:in `push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/provider.rb:199:in `block in deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/provider.rb:199:in `deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/dpl-1.10.6/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/dpl:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I've discovered the answer to both questions.

First, the weird error was due to this:

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script:
      - do something
      - do something else
      - do another thing
```

The normal `script` directive in Travis CI builds accepts a sequence, but the `script` directive within the `script` deploy provider is different and only accepts a single string, which it invokes as a single command. You can't even pass in a multi-line string. Still doesn't work. I filed [this bug](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-yml/issues/92) with Travis about that and, until that is fixed, found a temporary workaround for that issue using `before_deploy` (below).

Second, if you use the top-level `deploy` directive, then deployment will run as part of the build stage instead of as its own stage. The documentation is not clear on this, but it was an easy fix.

Finally, you can only encrypt a single file, not multiple files, so you if you have multiple secret files, you have to use a Tar archive and encrypt that.

Here's the working Travis build after I worked out all my issues:

```
language: java
sudo: false
cache:
  directories:
    - "$HOME/.cache"
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      dist: trusty
      jdk: oraclejdk8
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      dist: trusty
      jdk: openjdk8
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      dist: xenial
      jdk: oraclejdk11
    - stage: build
      os: linux
      dist: xenial
      jdk: openjdk11
    - stage: deploy
      os: linux
      dist: xenial
      jdk: openjdk8
      before_deploy:
        - openssl aes-256-cbc -in .travis.secrets.tar.enc -out .travis.secrets.tar -d
        - tar -xvf .travis.secrets.tar
        - rm .travis.secrets.tar
        - gpg --import travis.gpg
        - rm travis.gpg
        - mv settings.xml $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
      deploy:
        - provider: script
          script: "mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -P sign -B -V -e"
          on:
            tags: true
          skip_cleanup: true
        - provider: releases
          api_key:
            secure: CKKEi9hoN...xbzZByUU80Q=
          file_glob: true
          file:
            - $HOME/.m2/repository/io/path/to/project-*.pom
            - $HOME/.m2/repository/io/path/to/project-*.pom.asc
          on:
            tags: true
stages:
  - build
  - name: deploy
    if: tag =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(-[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*)?$
install:
  - gpg --version
  - mvn process-resources -B -V -e
script:
  - mvn test -B -V -e
```

Comment: this saved us hours of debugging. you deserve a medal.